# Azure DevOps configure code coverage with JaCoCo

Tags: azure-devops, code-coverage, jacoco

I want to view code coverage in Azure DevOps.

So I configured my `azure-pipelines.yml` like this:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site" /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=jacoco /p:CoverletOutput=$(Build.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TestResults/Coverage/'''
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    maximumCpuCount: true

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*test.dll
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    codeCoverageEnabled: true
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: 'JaCoCo'
    summaryFileLocation: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TestResults/Coverage/*.xml'
```

and the nuget-package `coverlet.collector` was added by Azure DevOps checkin.
I also added the part `/p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=jacoco /p:CoverletOutput=$(Build.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TestResults/Coverage/` in step *VSBuild*.

However, when I click on the last run pipeline it only shows a button `Download code coverage results` with a link to a `.coverage`-file.

I decided for `JaCoCo` over `Cobertura` for no specific reason, so taht can be changed if necessary.

How can I view code coverage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure DevOps configure code coverage with JaCoCo

This is a [known issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/662921/code-coverage-report-display-blank.html) on Azure devops. Now, we could only download the report, and open it with Visual Studio.

**Azure devops only support the download link for .coverage files currently. The white page you see is a UI glitch. This scenario is only supposed to render a download link to the coverage file.**

Besides, this issue has been submitted in this earlier suggestion ticket linked here:

[support vstest .coverage "code coverage" build results tab](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/366142/support-vstest-coverage-code-coverage-build-result.html)

This feature request is **On Roadmap**, I believe it will be released soon, you can follow this thread to know its latest feedback.

Hope this helps.